# setState in function callback

Tags: reactjs

I need to call setState in a callback for my function. For some reason it doesn't seem to get called. What's the right way of calling setState outside the component? Here is my code:

```
service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                (results) => {
                    console.log(this.setState())
                    this.setSate({
                        addressMarker: {
                            icon: results[0].image,
                            title: results[0].name,
                            lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                            lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            else
                console.log("ERROR!: "+results)
        })
```

I've updated the code as follows:

```
service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, (results, status) => {
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(this.setState())
                        this.setSate({
                            addressMarker: {
                                icon: results[0].image,
                                title: results[0].name,
                                lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                                lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng
                            }
                        })
                }
                else
                    console.log("ERROR!: "+results)
            })
```

but still the variable doesn't change..

Comment: What do you mean outside the component? Can you share the component?

Comment: `this.setState()` no state update

Comment: where do you call this service? and how? share the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra layer of arrow function in your callback.  Delete the line `(results) => {` and the matching `}`.  As written, the logic is "if the status is OK, then produce a function but don't do anything with it".  You already have access to `results` as the first parameter to the outer function.